# How do I see all of the directories shared using Nautilus Sharing Options?

Tags: nautilus, samba, file-sharing

When you share a directory using samba, you can do this system-wide by editing the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file (the advanced way) or by right-clicking a directory using Nautilus and selecting 'Sharing Options' (the easy way). However, while I can see what directories are shared system-wide by looking at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, if I share directories using Nautilus, I do not know what directories that I (or other users) have shared.

So how do I list all the directories that have been shared by samba using Nautilus Sharing Options for all the users on a system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `/var/lib/samba/usershares/` which contains a directory full of different user's shares.

Since one home folder can only ever be shared once, it makes sense to put them here in a central location. The directory is writeable by the `sambashare` group, so you need to be in that group in order to create a share.

Each share is then owned by the user that created it.